# Add a custom command line to Makefile.am in order to fail the build

Tags: linux, build, makefile, automake

I have some linux command line which when its output is not empty I need to fail the build.
We perform builds via makefiles that are constructed with AutoMake.
There are many nested Makefile.am.
I tried to add this check to several makefile.am in different ways but couldn't succeed, mostly it is not accepted by the syntax or just doesn't work.
If I just put this command line after label of make-install and shows an error in the output but doesn't fail the build, this is as far as I got.
Would appreciate some snippet that works.
Thanks

Comment: make-install is much too late to fail the build. What command did you try? What target are you trying to do this for? What do the relevant snippets of automake files (for this target) look like?

Comment: I tried several, e.g.: 
install: install-am  
if [[ -n $(xmlwf applicative_xml/exchange.xml) ]]; then \
    exit(1);  \
fi

The current automake is very simple:
dist_conf_DATA = logInfo.conf \
   p0f.fp

Comment: How does that automake file generate the `applicative_xml/exchange.xml` file?

Comment: It doesn't generate it. It is predefined XML file.

Comment: I would think that build time would be much too late to xmlwf check a manually created file. Why are you not doing that at commit/submission/etc. time? That being said if you aren't generating the file during the build then you need to find some other build-time target that runs early in the build process and add your xmlwf check to that rule.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to find such place? I am not really able to add such commands that fail the build anywhere in the makefile.am.

Comment: You can add normal rules to Makefile.am files and they will be copied through. Find a target that runs early in your build (possibly even `all`) and add an explicit prerequisite on your (.PHONY) well-formedness check target. Then add the rule that runs your check for that phony target. That might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up putting this check in the Jenkins build script which is easier.

Another cool solution I used was to create GIT hooks in the pre commit stage for all the clients that can commit (we use GIT as the repository) and check the command there. This way no one can commit unless this check works perfectly.
I modified this example to create such hook: http://codeinthehole.com/writing/tips-for-using-a-git-pre-commit-hook/
Note that symbolic link did not work for me so I used hard link which worked perfectly.